# How to call a function that uses recordID from test class?

Tags: unit-test

im trying to write a test class to some apex class i have. this is the function im writing tests to:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string getDunsByRecordId(id currentRecordID,String currentSObjectName) { 
    List<Account> accounts;
    List<Lead> leads;
    String q = 'SELECT DunsNumber FROM Account  where Id=:currentRecordID limit 1'; // retrieves Dunsnumber if im in an account record
    String q2 = 'SELECT DunsNumber FROM Account where Id IN (SELECT AccountID FROM Contact Where Id =:currentRecordID)'; // retrieves Dunsnumber if im in a contact record
    String q3 = 'Select CompanyDunsNumber From Lead where Id =:currentRecordID'; // retrieves Dunsnumber if im in a lead record
    if (currentSObjectName == 'Account')
    {
        accounts = Database.query(q);
    }
    else if (currentSObjectName == 'Contact')
    {
        accounts = Database.query(q2);
    }
    else if (currentSObjectName == 'Lead')
    {
        leads = Database.query(q3);
        return (!leads.isEmpty()) ? leads[0].CompanyDunsNumber : '';
    }
    return (!accounts.isEmpty()) ? accounts[0].DunsNumber : '';
}
```

as you can see, this function receives a recordID from the component.

i have the following functions in test class:

```
private static void testGetDunsByRecordId(id currentRecordID,String currentSObjectName, String expectedResult) { 
    Test.loadData(Lead.sObjectType,'LeadTestData');
    
    string duns = AccConListController.getDunsByRecordId(currentRecordID,currentSObjectName);
    
    System.assertEquals(expectedResult,duns,'');   
    
}
@isTest private static void testgetDunsByRecordIdQ3() {
    testGetDunsByRecordId('101','Lead','999999999');
}
```

when i run this test i receive the error:

> System.StringException: Invalid id: 101
>
> Class.AccConListControllerTestClass.testgetDunsByRecordIdQ3: line 58, column 1

when i call the function inside testgetDunsByRecordIdQ3(), i enter a string instead of an ID, i don't know how to pass an id... couldn't find an answer
please help

Comment: Test.loadData create and inserts a lead? you need to insert record before you use its id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are not passing a valid Id. 101 is not a valid value for a field type Id.

Since you are using the passed Id in a query in the actual class, I suggest passing a legitimate ID so that the query returns some records and doesn't end up throwing an exception.

So in order to do that, call your `Test.loadData` function in your `testgetDunsByRecordIdQ3` method before calling the function `testGetDunsByRecordId`. I assume you have loaded some leads records using `Test.loadData`.

Then, write an SOQL query to fetch a legitimate Lead Id and pass it to `testGetDunsByRecordId` method.

```
Lead lObj = [Select Id from Lead LIMIT 1];
testGetDunsByRecordId(lObj.Id,'Lead','999999999');
```

Do similar thing when you are writing a test method for Account as well.

Comment: Glad I could help.